# Marshal json file into map

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, go, slice

I have a largish (10mb) JSON file which I am attempting to unmarshal into a map so I can read it from memory when required.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to key the map by the id of each row in the json or even if this is the idiomatic approach to the problem.

It contains a lot of nested data but for simplicity it's basically this:

```
[{"id": "086687173", "count": 5}, {"id": "078382574", "count": 3}]

type Item struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
    Count int `json:"count"`
}

data := []Item  // am able to marshal into an array
data := make(map[string]Item) // cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]Item


bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./templates/data.json")
err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &data)

fmt.Println(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that I can't figure out how to key the map by the id

You can't index the map because you don't have any maps.

Your input JSON is a JSON array, so you can unmarshal that into a Go slice. After that you have to build a Go map yourself. And then you can index that map by `Id`:

```
m := map[string]*Item{}
for i := range data {
    m[data[i].Id] = &data[i]
}

fmt.Println(m)
fmt.Println(m["086687173"])
fmt.Println(m["078382574"])
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qSsV_7v2gwN)):

```
[{086687173 5} {078382574 3}] <nil>
map[078382574:0x43015c 086687173:0x430150]
&{086687173 5}
&{078382574 3}
```

Note that if you initially would've used a pointer slice `[]*Item`, creating the map would be simpler:

```
m := map[string]*Item{}
for _, item := range data {
    m[item.Id] = item
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BZVEBGs1vuP).

Comment: thanks, i think i was just expecting to be able to marshal straight to a map without the intermediate array step